# TOC and glossaries are green even with linkcolor=black in hypersetup

Tags: hyperref

I have been given a LaTeX preamble to use for my PhD dissertation, which have the following configuration for hyperref:

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}
% change to \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}, in order to remove colorlinks 
% change to \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 1 1}, in order to use colorlinks 
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0},
%   colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black}
```

However, with this configuration, both my table of contents and where I use `\gls{}` still turns green. I am not altering links in any other manner and I cannot find anything in the preamble that should cause this.
Any ideas for what I can try?

I can submit the full preamble if need and my list packages

Edit:

A colleague found the solution. In a nested preamble file we both had missed, was another hypersetup, that overwrote the above configuration.

Comment: Don't show the full preamble, but make a small but complete example so that one can test your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but wouldn't that need the full preamble?

Comment: no, remove probably unrelevant packages one-by-one until you have a small example.

Comment: Okay I will try and do that